# Which European (incl. Turkey) hub has the biggest seats capacity to destinations in Africa

Tags: air-travel, europe, factoids, africa

I would like to know which hub has more seats to any destination in Africa, no matter where.

For one particular airport consider how many seats there are available in total in a given month or year on all planes leaving from this particular airport to anywhere in Africa. For which airport in Europe is this number the highest?

Thanks,
Avi

Comment: Please explain what you mean by 'seats' so that we can understand what you're asking.

Comment: I think the question is asking this: for one particular airport consider how many seats there are available in total everyday on all planes leaving from this particular airport to anywhere in Africa. For which airport in Europe is this number the highest? But maybe OP can clear that up.

Comment: Hi and welcome. I have put the question on hold for now to give you a chance to clarify it. Please add all the details requested by the other comments. Once this is done we will reopen the question.

Comment: Hi, It is exactly what martin.koeberl said, but in a month or year rather than a day, thanks!

Comment: Excellent. Please [edit](http://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/90693/edit) your question adding this information.

Comment: Hi, I already clarified it in the description. Why is it still on hold?